# A way in python to get the current loggedIn username of device connected on the network

Tags: python, networking

What my script is currently doing?

I have developed a python script using python-nmap module which is currently able to get list of the device connected on the network and popup alert message when any new device get connected or disconnected with details such ass IP address,MAC address.

What I want to add?

Along with the details of IP and MAC, I want my script to fetch the details of currently loggedIn user on the particular system.

Suppose three devices and connected on the network, having IP 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.5, I want my script to fetch the currently loggedIn user on the system using above mentioned IP addresses connected on the network.